# How do I get code snippets working in Visual Studio Code for Python (on Windows 10)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm following this video: https://youtu.be/W--_EOzdTHk?t=174

I've installed the python extension and while I get some intellisense I have no option for code snippets.

So if I type `i` it'll suggest `if`, `import`, `in`, etc. but I get no option for snippets like in the video.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you looking for PyLance? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance

Comment: @OneCricketeer I show Pylance as installed and enabled. It must have been installed with the regular python extension.

Comment: they have removed the default snippets from the Python extension, you have to get them from the repo and install them as user snippets, search SO for a link, or browse the repo back in time until you get a snippets reference in `package.json`